# g:sortableColumn missing controller name(How can I pass controller name to g:sortableColumn?)

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I'm using **g:sortableColumn** for my table but I get this error :

> Caused by UrlMappingException: Unable to create URL for mapping
>   [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?] and parameters [{sort=firstName, order=asc,
>   action=list}]. Parameter [controller] is required, but was not
>   specified!

This is my code:

```
    <g:sortableColumn property="firstName" title="FirstName"/>
```

And this is my class:

```
 package medicalautomation

class InformationDocs {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String idNum
    String sex
    String bloodType
    Date birthDay
    String job
    String backGround
    Double weight
    Double height
    Double bloodPressure
    Double bloogSugar
    String phoneNum
    String address
    String description


    static constraints = {
        firstName()
        lastName()
        idNum()
        sex()
        bloodType()
        birthDay()
        job()
        backGround(maxSize:5000 )
        weight(nullable: true)
        height(nullable: true)
        bloodPressure(nullable: true)
        bloogSugar(nullable: true)
        phoneNum(maxSize: 20)
        address(maxSize: 200)
        description(maxSize: 5000)


    }
}
```

Well its obvious that when I use it in another GSP page than the one in which it is linked to the controller, I have to pass the controller name.The problem is I don't know how ,and I'm not sure if it has anything to do with URL mapping.

Thanks for your help

My GSP code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery" />
<title>Welcome to Grails</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="topnav">
  <p style="color: white">Top Nav</p>
 </div>
<div class="sidenav">
 <div class="sidenavcontent" >
  <h1>HELLO!!!</h1>
  <ul>
   <g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">
   <li><g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.fullName}</g:link></li>
   </g:each>
  </ul>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <g:sortableColumn property="firstName" title="FirstName"/>
   <g:sortableColumn property="lastName" title="LastName"/>
   <g:sortableColumn property="idNum" title="ID Number"/>
  </tr>
   <g:each in="${medicalautomation.InformationDocs.list()}" var="info">
    <tr>
     <td><g:remoteLink id="${info.id}" controller="informationDocs" action="show" update="showdetails">${info.firstName}</g:remoteLink></td>
     <td>${info.lastName}</td>
     <td>${info.idNum}</td>
    </tr>
   </g:each>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="bodycont">
 <div id="showdetails"></div>
</div>
```

I send the **controller** using **params** map and it calls the **list action** correctly but there is a problem :

I changed the list action and it redirects to the gsp page that g:sortableColumn is but it seems that the order of the table is not changing.This is my code in controller:`redirect(uri: "?sort=${params.sort}&order=${params.order}")`

Comment: can you please put your GSP code where you use this **sortableColumn** for better understanding.

Comment: @ajaypanchal I updated the post

Comment: try adding params="${params}" to the <g:sortable tag... controllerName is ${controllerName} and actionName is ${actionName} as variables accesible in gsp / controllers

Comment: @vahid It works!!! Tnx

Comment: @vahid I updated the question would you take a look at that please?

Comment: If it works what is the update about, this is getting hard to follow. If you have a new problem I suggest you ask a new question. so far as params goes https://github.com/vahidhedayati/jssh/blob/03870079457bcceece382498ee4c629c0afe5bdc/grails-app/views/jsshadmin/_view_connections.gsp#L30-L32  in that params bit you can say controller:currentController

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you correctly, the gsp-page is not the
**views -> medicalautomation.informationDocs.index** one?

... if you would redirect the sortable-column to a different controller, you have to take the responsibility, to provide the same data as the list-method for this controller who displays initially the gsp-page and have to specify this gsp-page in the response ... (because after clicking the sortable-column, the same page is displayed again, with the list, sorted by the column-name)

and therefore, your

```
<g:each in="${medicalautomation.InformationDocs.list()}" var="info">
```

confuses me a bit, because there you call the DomainClass-list method directly without the params (where the sort-order is specified) and I think your sort-order would get discarded, even if you managed it to display it without the exception...?

In cases, where the depending list, which I want to display, is limited, I often use jQuery-DataTable. Which has a the possibility to sort the lines etc. builtin.

And:

In cases where I want to display a small collection of depending data, I usually use a jQuery.ajax call to get the data and modify the html through jQuery/Javascript ...

Hope I could help a bit.

Comment: Yes its not the controllers gsp.
And for explanation.As you mentioned clicking g:sortableColumn calls the list action of the controller